# How to group by hourly for each day of the week?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter

I have a long table with a datetime and value column. This is a short example of the dataframe. What I currently do is group by hour, weekday, month and I get the mean of the month or hour of all times.

This is for the hourly value: `hourly_value = df.groupby([lambda idx: idx.hour]).agg([np.mean, np.std])`

```
    datetime                    value 
0   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   0.22 
1   2018-01-01 00:35:00+01:00   0.31   
2   2018-01-02 00:30:00+01:00   1.15  
3   2018-01-02 00:35:00+01:00   1.80   
4   2018-01-03 00:30:00+01:00   2.60  
5   2018-01-03 00:35:00+01:00   2.30 
6   2018-01-04 00:30:00+01:00   1.90   
7   2018-01-04 00:35:00+01:00   2.10  
8   2018-01-05 00:30:00+01:00   2.90
```

Now what I want is the hourly value for each day. Monday every hour, Tuesday every hour, Wednesday every hour, ...

Can someone help me with this?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.groupby(lambda idx: (idx[1].hour, idx[1].strftime("%A"))).agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

output:

```
                value          
                 mean       std
(0, Friday)     2.900       NaN
(0, Monday)     0.265  0.063640
(0, Thursday)   2.000  0.141421
(0, Tuesday)    1.475  0.459619
(0, Wednesday)  2.450  0.212132
```

Where the index is (hour, weekday) pair.

But note that e.x. Mondays from different weeks are grouped into one group.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible first to pick the monday and then plot the hourly trend? I will do this then with every other weekday. At the end I want a list with every hour of the monday, of the tuesday and so on.

Comment: Similarly you can `groupby` the result by the weekday: `grouped.groupby(lambda idx: idx[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of calculating:

```py
df.resample('1D', on='datetime').agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

outputs:

```
                       value
             mean        std
datetime        
2017-12-31  0.265   0.063640
2018-01-01  1.475   0.459619
2018-01-02  2.450   0.212132
2018-01-03  2.000   0.141421
2018-01-04  2.900        NaN
```

Comment: This gives the values for the day. My goal is to have every monday grouped and the values for every hour of that day. I want to see a trend how the value is performing over a  Friday for example.